# ES6 async/await in classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a class that will send a post request (login), save the cookie and use that cookie for other operations such as download a file.

I created a local server that that will receive a post http method with user and password in it and a router called `/download` that will only be accessed if the user is logged in, otherwise it will return `you need to log in`.

The problem:
This is the prototype of my class (before hand):

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')

class ImageDownloader {
  constructor(username = null, password = null) {
    this.username = username
    this.password = password
    this.cookie = request.jar()

    this.init()
  }

  init() {
    // login and get the cookie
  }

  download() {
    // needs the cookie
  }

  query() {
    // needs the cookie
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code above I need the cookie for two operations that is `download` and `query` so I though about creating an `init` method that will do the initial operations such as login and call it right in the constructor so it will be initialized and put the cookie on the variable `this.cookie` to use everywhere, but it doesn't work, it seems that `init` is being called after every other method.

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')

class ImageDownloader {
  constructor(username = null, password = null) {
    this.username = username
    this.password = password
    this.cookie = request.jar()

    this.init()
  }

  async init() {
    await request({
      uri: 'http://localhost/login',
      jar: this.cookie,
      method: 'post',
      formData: {
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'admin'
      }
    }).catch(e => console.error(e))
  }

  async download() {
    await request({
      uri: 'http://localhost/download/image.jpg',
      jar: this.cookie
    })
    .then(b => console.log(b))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
  }

  query() {
    // ...
  }
}

const downloader = new ImageDownloader
downloader.download()
```

**It's returning to me that I need to log in (server response)**... BUT it works if I do this change:

```
async download() {
  await init() // <<<<<<<<<<<<
  await request({
    uri: 'http://localhost/download/image.jpg',
    jar: this.cookie
  })
  .then(b => console.log(b))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
}
```

It only works if I call `init` in the `download` method.

If I put `console.log(this.cookie)` in `download` it returns an empty `CookieJar` and if I put the same in `init` it will return the right cookie but it appears **AFTER** the execution of download even tho I called it on the constructor before calling `download`.

How to solve that? Thank you very much.

@edit

I made the changes that **@agm1984** and **@Jaromanda X** told me but it still doesn't work :(

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')

class ImageDownloader {
  constructor(username = null, password = null) {
    this.username = username
    this.password = password
    this.cookie = request.jar()

    this.init().catch(e => console.error(e))
  }

  async init() {
    return await request({
      uri: 'http://localhost/login',
      jar: this.cookie,
      method: 'post',
      formData: {
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'admin'
      }
    })
  }

  async download() {
    return await request({
      uri: 'http://localhost/download/image.jpg',
      jar: this.cookie
    })
  }

  query() {
    // ...
  }
}

const downloader = new ImageDownloader
downloader.download()
          .then(b => console.log(b))
          .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

But then again... it doesn't work unless I call `init` inside `download`.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't understand why I would return anything as the operations inside `init` and `download` doesn't need to be shared anywhere and the `request-promise-native` will put the jar in the `this.cookie` for me (what I need), but the thing is the order things are running. Adding `await init()` in `download` is behaving like "I have to wait for `init` to finish and then continue" (something like that), but as I called `this.init` in the constructor I though it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I misread your code

Comment: as I said, I misread your code, ignore my changes :p - most of them are not required as I screwed up **my** knowledge of async/await :p

Comment: That is okay, you tried to help and I fully understand what you mean. Thank you anyway.

Comment: the problem now is that `download` wont wait for `init`

Comment: in constructor, try adding `this.initp = this.init();` ... then in `download` add `await this.initp;` as the first line

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to be calling `init` in every single method I need the cookie, so in a logical way I thought: what about I created a method that is called once in the constructor and used afterwards everywhere, well, in theory it works like a charm, but in practice, nah. I thought that the `await` would do the trick and wait until it finishes, and as I'm calling `download` using the concrete method of `ImageDownloader` I also though that it would call `download` after `init` anyways.

Comment: @JaromandaX It does work but it's going to be making requests to login over and over again every time I call `download ` or use in another method, it's the same to call: `await this.init()` to `await this.initp`

Comment: not if you do what I last suggested ... add `this.initp = this.init();` to `constructor` (runs once), then add `await this.initp;` as the first line of `download` **but** you'll also need to `return await request({` in `download` (as you are NOW doing) if you want to get to the resolved data

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works, the only thing is that I'm not that comfortable yet and not happy that there isn't another way of doing that without the need to be calling `await this.initp` in every method that needs the cookie, it looks so spaghetti. :(

Comment: I would separate the concerns and inject the cookie into the image downloader so that your code becomes more like: `const cookie = await getCookie(username, password); const image = await (new ImageDownloader(cookie)).download();`

Comment: There are 2 ways. Either you need to maintain a session (request session) or you need to maintain cookies as @k0pernikus suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `init` is asynchronous. Using it like this:

```
const downloader = new ImageDownloader;
downloader.download();
```

The `download` function is being executed while `init` still did not finish yet.

I wouldn't call the init method in the constructor. What I would do is something like this:
1- remove the init call from the constructor.
2- use the class like this:

```
const downloader = new ImageDownloader();
downloader.init()
  .then(() => downloader.download());
```

and if you are calling init in an `async` function you can do:

```
await downloader.init();
const result = await downloader.download();
```